# How to fit eight plots in the same .eps output

Tags: plot, gnuplot

As the title says, I want to fit eight plots (four in the left column and four in the right) using the multiplot command. The basic skeleton of my script is the following:

```
reset

set term postscript eps enhanced "Helvetica" 20 size 7in, 7in
set output 'kaos_pl2d.eps'

set size 1,1

set multiplot layout 2, 2

unset key

set origin 0, 0.75
plot ...

set origin 0, 0.50
plot ...

set origin 0, 0.25
plot ...

set origin 0, 0
plot ...

set origin 0.5, 0.75
plot ...

set origin 0.5, 0.50
plot ...

set origin 0.5, 0.25
plot ...

set origin 0.5, 0
plot    

unset multiplot

reset

set terminal windows

quit
```

Unfortunately, the output is not the desired one, since all the plots are overlapping each other. I suspect that this is caused by using wrong setup to set origin and set size. I am not very familiar with gnuplot, so I would be very grateful if you could help me solving this issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use, `multiplot layout`, you do not have to explicitly `set origin` and `set size` for each plot--that is handled automatically.

Your problem is also that you give multiplot a layout of 2x2 when you want eight plots.  Try

```
set multiplot layout 4,2
```